# Deleting specific element of an array of a particular collection - mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am new to mongoDb. I have created a collection named task that has comments field which is array along with other fields.
I need to delete specific comment of the task. There is a delete button in each comment. Both task id and comment id are available.
Now how to delete/edit specific comment of the task?

Thanks in advance

task api

```
{
   "status":true,
   "task":[
      {
         "_id":"61dfef323a6ee474c4eba926",
         "description":"hello there",
         "title":"hello",
         "comments":[
              {
                 "comment_id":1,
                 "username":"test",
                 "comment":"abcd",
                 "status":true,
              }, 
              {
                "comment_id":2,
                 "username":"test",
                 "comment":"abcdsdfsdf",
                 "status":true,
              }
           ],
         "createdAt":"2022-01-13T09:21:54.795Z",
         "updatedAt":"2022-01-13T09:21:54.795Z",
         "__v":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Task model schema

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  comments: [Object],
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

task route

```
router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
  const { taskId } = req.body;
  Task.find(taskId)
    .then(task => {
      if (task) res.json({ status: true, task })
      else res.json({ status: false, msg: task not available.' })
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Task.updateOne(
  { _id: taskId },
  {
    $pull: { comments: { 'comment_id': commentId } }
  }
);
```

Also MongoDB embraces camelCase, so renaming `comment_id` field to camelCase (or even simply `id`) might improve readability.